# C# - How to deserialise the type within an ICollection JSON property?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization, json-deserialization

I've got some JSON in this format that includes a collection.

```
{
  "Store": 12,
  "TransactionItems": {
    "$type": "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[[BaseTransactionItem, Common]], mscorlib",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$type": "TransactionSaleItem, Common",
        "Description": "Grey Shirt",
        "ActualSalePrice": 40.0,
        "ActualSalePricePerItem": 40.0
      },
      {
        "$type": "TransactionReturnItem, Common",
        "Description": "Red Shirt",
        "ActualSalePrice": -30.0,
        "ActualSalePricePerItem": -30.0
      }
    ]
  },
  "CountryCode": "GB"
}
```

When this is deserialised using Newtonsoft's nuget package, I get access to the `TransactionItems` which has a collection of two items and they're both of type `BaseTransactionItem`. When looping through each of these items, how can I get the type of each item i.e. `TransactionSaleItem` and `TransactionReturnItem`?

Simplified C# code:

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Transaction : IEquatable<Transaction>
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Store { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public ICollection<BaseTransactionItem> TransactionItems { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(TransactionOrderItem))]
[KnownType(typeof(TransactionReturnItem))]
[KnownType(typeof(TransactionSaleItem))]
public class BaseTransactionItem : IEquatable<BaseTransactionItem>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class TransactionReturnItem : BaseTransactionItem, IEquatable<TransactionReturnItem>
{
}

[DataContract]
public class TransactionSaleItem : BaseTransactionItem, IEquatable<TransactionSaleItem>
{
}
```

Comment: Show us your actual code, including the models

Comment: You can register a custom `JsonConverter` to deserialize the `"$type"` to a `Type type {get; set;}`.

Comment: @DavidG I've added some to the op

Comment: How are you both serialising and deserialising?

Comment: @DavidG Newtonsoft's JsonConvert.SerializeObject and DeserializeObject methods. Looks like I can get it to deserialise if I create new JsonSerializerSettings with TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto.

Answer (score 1):

Each object specifies its type with the `"$type"` field. You should be ableto map these keys against `TransactionSaleItem` and `TransactionReturnItem` respectivly.

If you are using System.Text.Json this is done with a [JsonDerivedType attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism?pivots=dotnet-7-0):

```
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(TransactionSaleItem), typeDiscriminator: "TransactionSaleItem, Common")]
[JsonDerivedType(typeof(TransactionReturnItem), typeDiscriminator: "TransactionReturnItem, Common")]
public class BaseTransactionItem
{
   ...
}
```